# how to implement string list from _ListItem to assetPath?

Tags: string, list, flutter, wallpaper

i've been working with wallpaper app.
i manage to call the path list for wallpaper,
i can make this work on image card list but i can't manage to do it work with assetPath for WallpaperManager

Please help, is there any way to do it?

```
Future<void> setWallpaperFromAsset() async {
setState(() {
  _wallpaperAsset = "Loading";
});
String result;
String assetPath = ('Load List here');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a parameter `assetPath` to `setWallpaperFromAsset`

```dart
  Future<void> setWallpaperFromAsset(String assetPath) async {
    setState(() {
      _wallpaperAsset = "Loading";
    });
    String result;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      result = await WallpaperManager.setWallpaperFromAsset(
          assetPath, WallpaperManager.HOME_SCREEN);
    } on PlatformException {
      result = 'Failed to get wallpaper.';
    }
  }
```

And you register the `onPressed` callback with:

```
RaisedButton.icon(
  onPressed: () => setWallpaperFromAsset(item),
  icon: Icon (Icons.wallpaper, size: 20),
  label: Text('homescreen')),
)
```